# I'm confused by the docs on whether to use postgresql or postgresql_psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm getting readyto deploy my app onto heroku and I have seen tutorials that say
download psycopg2 and then to this

```
ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
```

ThenI have read others that have the backend like this

```
ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
```

which is the correct way and why? It seems to work either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using latest Django (1.9), then better to use postgres. Another ENGINE is old one, but it still works for compatibility.

More on this you can read in official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ENGINE).

Comment: This is quite literally the opposite of the correct situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django 1.9+, then use `django.db.backends.postgresql`. It's much easier to remember!

For older versions of Django, you have to use `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2`.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#engine):

> The `django.db.backends.postgresql` backend is named `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` in older releases. For backwards compatibility, the old name still works in newer versions.